# Determining which version of a plugin is installed in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin, package-control

I tried to look up something simple like Package Control to determine if its version 2.x or 3.x installed, but even when browsing the Installed Packages folder, the only thing I could find was a created date of the plugin - created date shouldn't be used for version verification.

Checking out the website: https://packagecontrol.io/channel_v3.json it has a version number as part of the package, setting, but how would a Sublime User retrieve this for an installed package?

I don't imagine if there is any major difference between operating systems, but if you know of anything major (not available in one), please list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the command palette search for "Package Control: List Package" There you will see `v<version number>` under the package name.

Comment: So how can this be done without using Package Control library.  Someone was telling me that they could no longer use Package Control on whatever machine they were using.

Comment: @vol7ron in that case they'll need to get rid of Package Control and reinstall it.

Comment: @MattDMo that's the issue, I believe their proxy is not allowing them to install it, but I think that expands beyond what the original question was about

Comment: @vol7ron true. If they want help, just have them post a question here. There are ways of getting around proxy difficulties most of the time.